# How to increase height of textarea in npm medium-editor?

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

Even after defining row height a single line textarea appears.

```
<textarea rows="10" id="" name="" class="editable "></textarea>
<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');                             
</script>
```

Comment: Do you even see the textarea when running this code??

Comment: Yes, but it is a single line.

Comment: Instead of text-area, medium shows `p` tag element. Ref: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/demo/textarea.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different way to increase the height of an medium editor, Not a textarea.

Medium will shows a `contenteditable` div instead of textarea in the editor.

```
.medium-editor-textarea {
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

OR

```
<textarea class="editable medium-editor-textarea">
    <p><br></p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p><br></p>
</textarea>
```

Contenteditable div will introduce `p` tag for each line.

Ref: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/demo/textarea.html